# VS2019's ide can't identify asio's namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, asio

I was intrested in asio library,and since I've never used boost before,I download the standalone edition of asio.
I was using vs2019 and the code from example folder worked well,it can be compiled and executed.
The asio.hpp is included and the namespace asio can be identified.

```
#include "asio.hpp"
```

But vs2019's IDE just can't go further.

```
using asio::ip::tcp;
```

The IDE didn't 'think' tcp is a namespace,even it do 'know' where it is.
Using F12 shortcut the IDE can jump to tcp.hpp and find the class,but don't take tcp as a member of ip namespace.
Same situation occured in the whole file , leaving red underlines here and there.

[how can i add picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vxjQ.png)

I think there maybe something to do with intellisense,but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Please describe what you actually saw, not just your interpretation. "The IDE didn't 'think' tcp is a namespace" is not useful without the actual output, for example. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: does your code compile?